# how to call a function in angularjs when model length is in multiple of 3

Tags: angularjs

I have an input field, so I have to call a function for autosuggestion whenever user type 3, 6 ,9 characters. Means in mulitple of 3. I tried ng-change but it is only working for single value

```
ng-change="(myNgModel.length >= 3  ) && searchUser(myNgModel)"
```

Comment: Please share the codes which you have tried.

Comment: ng-change will fire any time the input value changes. The suggestion by @NTP is what I would also suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the length check inside your searchUser function. You can add an if condition so that your search logic would only run when your input's length is multiple of 3.

html

```
ng-change="searchUser(myNgModel)"
```

js

```
$scope.searchUser = function(myNgModel){
    if(myNgModel.length % 3 == 0){
        //search user logic
    }
}
```